# !file ended error when using \nobibliography*

Tags: bibentry

I have the following setup

```
 \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\nobibliography*

\section{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{bob}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

However when I try to compile I get the following error.

```
! File ended while scanning use of \BR@c@bibitem.<inserted text>\par \nobibliography
```

I assumed this was a missing } somewhere in my bib file but I have had a look and there are no such errors. I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the issue could be. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

- full class available here http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

Comment: You should provide a link to `CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls`, at least...

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks for the comment, would the class make much difference in this situation? it compiles fine untill I add the \nobibliography command. 

the full class is at this link http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/  - Thanks again

Comment: It could be that there is a conflict between hyperref's backref and bibentry. A workaround is to use lualatex and luabibentry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\nobibliography*` can be used only if you are going to use `\bibliography{mybib}` later in the document (supposing `mybib.bib` is your bibliography file).

In your case you have to use

```
\nobibliography{mybib}
```

Also remember that it is needed to declare a bibliography style, e.g.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Thus, modifying your MWE to

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{mybib}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{bob}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

will give the expected result.

P.S. Remember to run `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdlatex`

---

A compilable example just to show that the above code works:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{biblatex-examples}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{angenendt}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]